# How to Open a new Chrome session in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am a python beginner, the latest update in chrome driver is unable to open Chrome on windows without creating a session, how do I create a new session every time using python?

I am getting the following error -

```
**~/opt/anaconda2/envs/p36workshop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, keep_alive)
     79                     remote_server_addr=self.service.service_url,
     80                     keep_alive=keep_alive),
---> 81                 desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
     82         except Exception:
     83             self.quit()

~/opt/anaconda2/envs/p36workshop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in __init__(self, command_executor, desired_capabilities, browser_profile, proxy, keep_alive, file_detector, options)
    155             warnings.warn("Please use FirefoxOptions to set browser profile",
    156                           DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
--> 157         self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
    158         self._switch_to = SwitchTo(self)
    159         self._mobile = Mobile(self)

~/opt/anaconda2/envs/p36workshop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in start_session(self, capabilities, browser_profile)
    250         parameters = {"capabilities": w3c_caps,
    251                       "desiredCapabilities": capabilities}
--> 252         response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
    253         if 'sessionId' not in response:
    254             response = response['value']

~/opt/anaconda2/envs/p36workshop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~/opt/anaconda2/envs/p36workshop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 83**
```

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the same driver version as your current chrome installation?

Comment: Open Chrome >Settings> About chrome and check the version number. Make sure it matches the driver version

Comment: Thanks a lot, @AdarshKumar, turns out I was using the older version of the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explaining whats wrong. The version of chrome driver you have cannot be used for chrome v83.

How do you check for what chrome version you are using?:

1. open chrome and write this in the url bar:

```
chrome://settings/help
```

2. This will open up the about section and you should able to see the current version of chrome you have. For example i have the latest version `85.0.4183.83` which is chrome85.

Make sure you download the correct chrome driver based on this.